# Slow Loading of SQL Server data to Oracle through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis-2012

I have developed one SSIS package , which is supposed to load data from sql server to oracle database server. I am using SSDT Visual Studio 2015  and to make connect with oracle from SSIS I had to install "ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.1) i.e. ODTwithODAC122011" driver .
Earlier using the same driver I used to load data from SQL Server dev environment into my  oracle's localhost database server 18C so it was not taking much  time to load but now I am supposed to connect to Oracle Development Server 19C . So when I am loading data in Oracle Development Server 19C through SSIS(through data flow task) , its taking hours to load even for a single table which is bit concerning.Is it because of incompatibility issue connecting with Oracle 19c ??

What should I do resolve this issue ??

Comment: Any investigation into something being to slow first needs to figure out exactly what the bottleneck is.  Let's start with-- where is everything running?  I'm guessing SSIS and SQL Server are running on your local machine and the two source Oracle databases are running on two different remote servers.  Are those servers on the same network segment or on different network segments?  Can you fire up SQL Developer (something that uses a different connection method) to both databases and run a `select *` query and see how long it takes to fetch all the data from the different databases?

Comment: Also there's a special SSIS connector for Oracle that enables faster loading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-destination?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also ensure your fetch sizes (for select) or array bind sizes (for insert) are reasonable... thousands of rows at a time, not tens of rows, and certainly not one-row-at-a-time.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , the SSIS connector for oracle needs version above SSDT Visual Studio 2015 and I cannot upgrade that as per company's strict policy

Comment: Why? You can use the free community edition for SSIS.